# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 when adding objects of array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to do a program with a method that receives a two dimensional 3*3 array with the information of several Professors (created in a class called "Professor") and gets the amount of hours they work, how much money they make per hour and add them up to a variable that returns the total amount that's paid to the professors. I've already created the classes, the array, the objects with the information using the constructor, and put each object in every index of the array.
However, when I loop through the array I always get this error message as output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Here's my code (The last two numbers on the objects are (in order) the amount of hours the professor works, and the money they make per hour. I created all the objects with the same information for testing purposes, so 8 would be the hours and 1.66 the amount of money:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Profesor arreglo[][];
    arreglo = new Profesor[3][3];

    Profesor profe1 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);
    Profesor profe2 = new Profesor(233849920, "Nuria", "Ramírez", 52, "F", 4, 2.84);
    Profesor profe3 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);
    Profesor profe4 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);
    Profesor profe5 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);
    Profesor profe6 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);
    Profesor profe7 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);
    Profesor profe8 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);
    Profesor profe9 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 1.66);

    arreglo[0][0] = profe1;
    arreglo[0][1] = profe2;
    arreglo[0][2] = profe3;

    arreglo[1][0] = profe4;
    arreglo[1][1] = profe5;
    arreglo[1][2] = profe6;

    arreglo[2][0] = profe7;
    arreglo[2][1] = profe8;
    arreglo[2][3] = profe9;


    System.out.println("La suma de los salarios es: " +sumaSalarios(arreglo));



}

public static double sumaSalarios(Profesor matriz[][]) {
    int sumaHoras = 0;
    double sumaValorHoras = 0;
    double salarios = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            sumaHoras = sumaHoras + matriz[i][j].getHoras();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
            sumaValorHoras = sumaValorHoras + matriz[i][j].getValorHora();
        }
    }

    return salarios = sumaHoras*sumaValorHoras;

}
```

Comment: arreglo[2][3] = profe9;
3 should be 2

Comment: Big question for a simple typo.  ;)

Comment: Well, I feel kind of lame now, heheh... Thanks a lot. Now my problem is that   the result of adding the total paid to the professors is giving me 0.0.

Comment: I understand that the current question fits the description for being off-topic. However, I do have a different question regarding the same project, and I believe it's not a typographical error, as before. Can I change the subject of the question and add my new inquiry on this same post, or should I do another one?

Comment: Definitely create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- array indices start at 0, but I bet you knew that already;
- arrays, once declared, are of a fixed size in Java; once they are allocated, **they cannot be shrinked nor expanded**.

Your `arreglo[2][3] = profe9;` line in your code will throw that error since you declared your array as being:

```
arreglo = new Profesor[3][3];
```

But your `Professor[]` array, referenced by `arreglo[2]`, only has 3 elements; with index `3`, you try and access its 4th element, which does not exist --> `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Which has quite a meaningful name ;)

---

Note: if you want a "resizable two-dimensional array", although it doesn't exactly fit that definition, you can have a look at Guava's `Table`

Answer (score 1):

```
Profesor arreglo[][];
arreglo = new Profesor[3][3];
```

Means that you have 3 index : 0, 1 and 2

you try to add a profesor at fourth index at : `arreglo[2][3] = profe9;`

Answer (score 1):

```
arreglo = new Profesor[3][3];
```

When you define your array here, you specify it should have a length of 3.
However the count starts at 0, so your 3 positions are 0, 1, and 2.

This means when you try to access index 3,

```
arreglo[2][3] = profe9;
```

you are trying to access the 4th item in the array, which does not exist, so it throws the exception.